# Keeping selected language in dropdown after page reload using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, antd, react-i18next

The problem is:

There is a landing page, a language switch added with ant design, specifically, through Select / Option. The translation was done via i18react lib.
So, it is necessary that when the page is reloaded, the selected language is displayed in the dropdown itself, and not reset to the default Language.
I know what can be done through document.cookie. But how? Well, I'll put languages ​​in cookies. And then, how to screw them into this Select so that the display of the selected language is saved on reboot?

My code is here and I don't know what to do.

```
const Option = Select.Option;
function ChangeLanguageDropdown({}) {
   const {i18n} = useTranslation();
   const changeLanguage = (lang) => {
       i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
   };

   Cookies.set('ru', 'Русский', { expires: 7 });
   Cookies.set('en', 'English', { expires: 7 });
   

   return (

       <div>
           <Select defaultValue={"Language"} style={{ width: 110}} onChange={changeLanguage}>
              <Option value="ru">{i18next.t("Русский")}</Option>
              <Option value="en">{i18next.t("English")}</Option>
           </Select>
               </div>
```

Comment: Add value={language} to <Select >. Add a hook const [lang, setLang] = useState(A);
A: Cookie.get('Language'). Not sure why do you need myCookie and otherCookie. Call Cookies.set in onChange handler. Try to use something short instead of i18next.t - like t = i18next.t. Install prettier ;) Make sure that Cookie.get is not called on server side if SSR is used.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I don't need myCookie and otherCookie, I tried to resolve the task but I cant.
Can you show me your solution in code? Please

Comment: sure https://codepen.io/VasyaPupin/pen/akXWEZ

Answer (score 1):

```
const {useState} = React
const { Select } = antd

const { Option } = Select;

const ChangeLanguageDropdown  = ({}) => {
   const [lang, setLang] = useState('en' /* Cookie.get('path.to.cookie') */);
   const changeLanguage = (lang) => {
     setLang(lang);
     /* Cookie.set('path.to.cookie', lang); */
     /* call i18n.changeLanguage(lang); */
   };

   return (
     <div><div>{lang}</div>
    <Select defaultValue={lang} style={{ width: 500}}  onChange={changeLanguage}>
     <Option value="ru">"Русский"</Option>
     <Option value="en">"English"</Option>
   </Select>
</div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<ChangeLanguageDropdown />, document.body)
```

Note that I've removed all i18n related code as well as Cookie lib (your setup of Codepen was #R%T$). Next time, start with some example that actually works (e.g. https://codepen.io/mugiseyebrows/pen/ExyJJQQ?editors=1111)

Comment: just a curiosity, why "antd"? What's wrong with MD or direct usage of styled components?